# PrimeNG p-table scrollable scrollHeight last row p-dropdown to open upwards

Tags: javascript, angular, primeng, primeng-turbotable, primeng-dropdowns

Using following config:

`"@angular/cli": "^7.3.9",
"primeng": "7.0.5",`

I have a page that uses PrimeNG's `<p-table>` which is `scrollable` and has a `scrollHeight` set to 100%. This table is wrapped within a `div` that has fixed height of `300px`.

Created Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ejdubg

Every row has a `p-dropdown`. In top rows when dropdown is opened, it opens downwards which is acceptable but when dropdown in the last row is opened, it open downwards too but should open upwards which is the default behavior of the `p-dropdown`.

Any suggestions what could be wrong here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add appendTo="body" on p-dropdown

```
<th *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.field">
                <p-dropdown appendTo="body" [options]="brands"></p-dropdown>
            </th>
```

Comment: Updated the stackblitz as per your answer but it still opens downwards and goes below the table. It should open upwards. Please check.

Comment: @KunalDethe i don't see that you updated the project. see the forked project is that what you needed? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xheopx

Comment: `appendTo="body"` helps to open the dropdown downwards and outside the table. I needed it to open upwards if no space is there below. ie. last row in the table. It does work out-of-the-box for `p-dropdown` and it did without `appendTo`. My problem was that someone set the `top` property to some `px` and `!important`.. which was wrong. Instead it should allow the dropdown to calculate `top` on its own. So its fixed now. Thank you.